# Various meanings of どうですか?

Tags: grammar, translation

This was a while back so I forget what the situation was exactly. I was asking an employee for help at a Bic Camera. If I recall correctly, I was asking something like "Are there other keyboards besides for the Windows OS?" Alternatively, I might have simply stated (not asking a question) that there are only keyboards for Windows OS. He replied to this with どうですか.

I know どうですか means "How is it?", but that is not the usage here. Assuming I asked a question, it seemed more like he was asking "Which one?", as in which operating system do I want a keyboard for. Assuming I simply made a statement, it was like "What is the situation?"

Does someone know what the usage might have been?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it was どれですか.

Comment: @AeonAkechi That could have been a possibility, but I remember even going like "Hm?" and he repeated it. Also, どれ would have been more natural for me to hear, yet I was surprised by his response. I have edited the question now, as I think I might not have even asked a direct question.

Comment: Did you ask the employee in Japanese?

Comment: @YuuichiTam Yes, I asked in Japanese. I don't remember what I said though. Maybe it was like "キーボードを探してるんですけど、Windows以外に対応するキーボードがないみたいですが…" But, that's just how I think I might have said it at the time.

Comment: If the employee said it while bringing you a keyboard, it means "How is this? ", which means 'Is this one you are looking for"? If the employee just said it, you might mishear it and it might be そうですか, which means "It may be so", "I see".

Comment: @YuuichiTam Oh, nah. I had just finished asking him a question (we weren't physically close to the keyboards). And his reply was definitely a question. Hm, I don't know. I guess if nobody can come up with a reasonable meaning, then maybe I did mishear どれですか, which seems to be most likely at this point.